# Using timeout in cmd without a keyboard

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-10

I want to use the *timeout* command in a cmd-script that runs on a system which has no input devices connected to it. The probelm is, even when I use the */NOBREAK* option, it still aborts and throws an error that no input device is found. Is there any way around this?

My code (nothing amazing here though):

```
timeout 10 /NOBREAK
*Do stuff*
```

Comment: for this it might be easier to just use ping instead `ping somedevice -n 100>nul`

Comment: @GerhardBarnard That did the trick for now, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for posting the code, as it makes the question more complete, but sadly the issue is that `timeout` expects some sort of input device, it also does not support input redirection, so there is not really a way around this.. Maybe there is some fancy methid I can figure out, but it does not really make sense as a similar result can be achieved using `ping`

Comment: Alright, I expected as much, thanks for taking the time though